# C# with MSSQL database Project Not running in another computers

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have Developed a C# project using Visual Studio 2015 and in this project, I have used the Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Database System.

The Problem is When I tried to run my project's Setup in other computer it shows the following Message whenever I run the project after the installation in another computer.

I have tried installing the MS SQL server in other computer it is displaying the same message. What I have done wrong?? Please help me. How to run my project in any computer?

[image]

Comment: The message is clearly showing that the app can't connect to the database. Check connection string + enable TCP on the SQL Server

Comment: Focus on the code that establishes the connection.

Comment: So you are planning to roll out a SQL Server instance to every computer that you want to run your project on?  That is a very strange way to deploy a solution.  Usually there will be a database running on one central machine (usually a server) and all the instances of the application connect to this.  The error could be that you are referencing a database on your local desktop, and this can't be seen by anyone but you on your network?

Comment: _"I have tried installing the MS SQL server in other computer it is displaying the same message"_ - do you need separate databases for your application? As well as checking SQL Server setup - it may be worth checking any firewall allows your application access.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev appears to be correct.  The poster does not realize how applications connect to SQL Server.  The application cannot connect to the database most likely because SQL Server is setup to not allow remote connections.  You need to enable TCP/IP via SQL Server Configuration.

Comment: I have enabled the TCP/IP via sql server configuration several times but still it shows the same message.

Comment: Please show us the connection string you are using: a) a working one and b) a non-working one. (You may want to blank out the password if there is one.)

Comment: I have found the error that the connection string is missing in another computer and I have fixed it. thank you all friends...

Answer (score -1):

You are not connected to SQL server yet. Make sure that the SQL services are running correctly. You can check them by clicking on My Computer->Manage->Services And Applications->Services.

Comment: The Sql servies is running. But again while running the exe it shows the same message

Comment: You have to Start all the services and set them to 'Auto' mode. Then you will get solution

Comment: Yes All are in automatic mode

Comment: All are in start mode and all are in running mode

Comment: Okay then try to connect to database on the client system. Use correct server name while connecting